# Using Protractor 'Expect'

Tags: protractor, jasmine2.0

I have some simple specs that run in sequence. The first one has an `expect` assertion for the webpage title - as does the second.

However, when I run the sequence, the first assertion passes but the second one fails and console.log shows that parts of the first spec's `expect` have become merged with the second spec's `expect`.

I have a feeling this is something to do with *promise*...please can someone confirm this (or deny it!!) and advise on a way to close the promise?

Thanks

**First Spec**

```js
describe('JL Homepage', function() {
//browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
browser.get('https://mwac-johnlewis-dev.digitalbridge.eu/landing');

 browser.sleep(10000);


it('should have a title', function(){
expect (browser.getTitle()).toBe('John Lewis Wallpaper Visualiser: 
Welcome');
});

});
```

**Second Spec**

```js
describe('Demo photo', function() {
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);


browser.sleep(3000);
element(by.xpath('html/body/webapp-app/div/div/webapp-johnlewis-landing/div/div/ul/li[2]/a/span')).click();

it('should load a demo room', function(){

    expect (browser.getTitle()).toEqual('John Lewis Wallpaper Visualiser: Design your room');

browser.sleep(3000);
});

});
```

**Console**

```js
2 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 19.409 seconds


**************************************************
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************

1) Demo photo should load a demo room
  - Expected 'John Lewis Wallpaper Visualiser: Welcome' to equal 'John 
  Lewis Wallpaper Visualiser: Design your room'.

Executed 2 of 2 specs (1 FAILED) in 19 secs.
[12:08:21] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[12:08:21] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[12:08:21] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[12:08:21] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
Admins-MacBook:jl_autotests davidredmayne$
```

Comment: all of your actions need to be inside an `it` block.  So that `browser.get` and your `click` method are not in the right place.  Move them inside the block, right before the `expect`

Comment: Hi - tried this but get asynchronous errors. Can I confirm the order please?1. Describe........2. Actions....3. It 4. Expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap all of your actions inside a valid Jasmine-block.

Find [an introduction of Jasmine with examples here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction) and the [latest API description here](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/global).

**As addition:** `browser.get()` is always a bit difficult to handle, because Protractor cannot know, if the page to load contains Angular. Therefore the test execution could continue, before the page is fully loaded.

To prevent too fast execution, use [`ExpectedConditions`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) and [`browser.wait()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait)

Here, how I suggest the first Spec to be:

```js
describe('JL Homepage', function() {
    //possibility for beforeAll(), beforeEach(), afterAll(), afterEach()
    it('should load the page and have a title', function(){
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.get('https://mwac-johnlewis-dev.digitalbridge.eu/landing');
        //wait until URL has changed
        browser.wait(EC.urlIs('https://mwac-johnlewis-dev.digitalbridge.eu/landing'),5000);
        //wait until page has finished loading
        browser.waitForAngular();
        expect (browser.getTitle()).toBe('John Lewis Wallpaper Visualiser: Welcome');
    });
});
```

Comment: You should NEVER use "browser.waitForAngular();" especially in an example, for Protractor. This has the function built in and running for EACH call. This is the whole principle with Protractor.

Comment: @EdLinac : Generally true, BUT there is always an exception for everything... and `browser.get()`-troubles are this exception. Browser.get() still causes lots of troubles, so the most stable solution so far turned out to be to wait for new URL, then explicitly execute `browser.watiForAngular()` (read i.e. [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2461) or [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2567) or [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3374))